# How to structure data per object per material

Tags: python, data-blocks

I'm working on an addon where I need to be able to store a float that is not just specific to a just an object or just a material, but both. I want to display this property next to the material in a UIList that is similar to the Material Slots UI list but also has an additional float field next to the material name that can be edited. I've been following [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UIList.html) documentation, which has been very helpful.

In the UI list, I can display the name of the materials in the list using `layout.prop(ma, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)`. I realize that I could add an additional property that belongs to just an object by registering a property using code like:

```
bpy.types.Object.my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
```

Similarly, I can register a float property with a material:

```
bpy.types.Material.my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
```

I can then display these properties in the UI list with a line something like:

```
row.prop(context.active_object, "my_float", emboss=False, icon_value = 0)
```

or:

```
row.prop(ma, "my_float", emboss=False, icon_value=0)
```

But what would be the best way to go about structuring the data in my addon such that for each object, each material has a separate float even if that material is shared with other objects? (e.g., `Cube` has `TestMaterial1` with a value of `0.5` for `my_float`, but `Cube.001` has the same material (`TestMaterial1`) in its material slot, but instead stores `5.4` for `my_float`.)

I'm assuming I'll need to use some kind of Enum, but I want to make sure that the data updates properly as new materials are added to the materials slot and whatnot. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your property is bound to bpy.types.Material, each instance of Material will initialize its own property.

What you want to do sounds like a bpy.types.Object property.
So, instead of:

```
bpy.types.Material.my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
```

you should do:

```
bpy.types.Object.my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
```

If that property is logically bound to a material, you can display it in the Material context.

In that case, context.active_object might not be available.
Instead you may try to use the global bpy.context.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the thoughtful answer and taking the time to respond! I really appreciate it. I realize now I should have structured my question better to explain more clearly what I was asking. I figured out what I needed to do more or less, and I can update this post when I get a chance. Thank you again so much for taking the time to respond!